# How do I create a new project located in a specific folder in eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, tycho

I am trying to set up a new set of projects for an RCP application. The main project contains folders which contain different kinds of projects and files. This file structure seems to be normal for tycho-based projects. See https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example.

The complete project hierarchy looks something like this:

[image]

According to best practice, the workspace and the git repository are separate. This means that, when I create a new project in one of the group folders (e.g. `bundles`), the project is created by default in the root of the workspace and, therefore, not in git. I need to override the default location and create a new location for the project which is within the git.

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Your parent/root project should not be a Java project. In the new (Java) project dialog, uncheck _Use default location_ checkbox at the top bellow the project name to choose the location you want.

Comment: @howlger You're right about the parent project, of course. I was just wondering if there is a smarter way to create a new project so that I don't always have to override the default location, browse to the parent folder, create a new folder etc.

Comment: Consider to become the hero who implements or fund this feature.